# jasmine-jquery implementation gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jasmine

I'm just starting with Jasmine and got it implemented in my Rails 4 project.

Just as a simple test I did:

```
//= require activities

describe('activities', function() {
  it("Some div to be div", function() {
    expect($('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>')).toBeChecked()
  });
});
```

This gives me the error `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toBeChecked'`. So I can only assume that jQuery or jasmine-jquery isn't properly loaded.

The documentation tells me to include jasmine-jquery and jquery to my yaml. So I did it as following:

```
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
  - jquery
  - jasmine-jquery

stylesheets:
  - stylesheets/**/*.css

helpers:
  - helpers/**/*.js

spec_files:
  - '**/*[sS]pec.js'

src_dir:

spec_dir: spec/javascripts
```

Am I not properly loading jasmine-jquery and jquery into my test environment, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This object `$('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>')` is just a jQuery object. It's not in DOM yet, so you can't say it's checked or not :)

To make it work, you need to show it at dom at first.

```
var checkbox;

checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>')
$('body').append(checkbox);

expect($("input[type='checkbox']").toBeChecked();
```

Comment: But it doesn't work that way in Jasmine does it? Or do I need to create a fixture where I put a checkbox or something?. Oh by the way; the object is perfectly fine to check. If it's on a stage or not should not matter if I'm correct.

Comment: This produces "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toBeChecked'" on my system.